# Briggs-Rauscher reaction doesn't oscillate and turns blue with Vitamin C

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, kinetics, color

I tried to recreate the [Briggs-Rauscher reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Briggs%E2%80%93Rauscher_reaction)  by using a solution of $\ce{H2O2}$, $\ce{KIO3}$, $\ce{H2SO4}$, $\ce{CH2(COOH)2}$, $\ce{MnSO4}$ and a soluble starch. I used [this recipe](https://www.scienceinschool.org/article/2009/antioxidants/#w2).

- In container 1, I added 295 ml of distilled water, and 205 ml of $\ce{H2O2}$ at 30% concentration.
- In container 2:  500 ml of distilled water 21.5 g of $\ce{KIO3}$ and 2.15 ml of $\ce{H2SO4}$.
- In container 3: 250 ml of distilled water, and 8 g  of $\ce{CH2(COOH)2}$ and 1.7g of $\ce{MnSO4}$ and 0.15 g of starch.

For the experiment, I added 10 ml of each container in the order 1, 2, 3 in a container with a magnetic stir plate. This was a clear mixture, whereas according to the recipe it should have been yellow and blue oscillating.

After waiting about 5 minutes I added 0.5 ml of Vitamin C. The things I used for vitamin C were: a 500mg tablet dissolved in water (50g or 100g), orange juice, apple juice pomegranite juice etc. What happened was: instantly when I added the vitamin C the solution turned blue. It then became transparent again within 2 to 40 seconds. (2 seconds was apple and orange juice, the 40 seconds in the high concentration of vitamin C). The solutions stayed clear for  the remainder of my time in the lab, which was up to 2 hours, depending on the trial.

---

The questions are:

1. Why was the solution clear when I added the first three containers? I was expecting yellow and blue oscillating.
2. Why did the solution turn blue when I added vitamin C, and then go back to clear? I was expecting the vitamin C to stop the oscillation to blue, and keep it at yellow for a time proportional to the vitamin C content. Instead adding the vitamin C made it turn blue for a length of time proportional to the concentration of Vitamin C. What happened?